# Does this qualify as a partial dependency?

Tags: database

Proper subset of candidate key along with non prime attribute determines non prime. Then is it partial dependency or in 2NF?

CAND KEY {AB} then BD-->C .

Answer (score 0):

This is how you define a partial dependency: For example you have a relation `R` with columns `A|B|C|D`.

Based on the functional dependency defined by business `AB` is designated as primary key (candidate key) and `B -> D` FD exists.

In that case, even though `AB` is PK; but non key column `D` is uniquely identified by only `B` (part of the key composition) and not by the entire key composition `AB`.

So, `D` here is partially dependent on key column and thus hold a `partial functional dependency` which is against `2NF`.

In your case, CK `AB` is not uniquely identifying all fields; `C` is partially dependent on `B`; moreover, `C` is dependent on non-key column `D`.

So, it has PFD (partial functional dependency) and surely not in 2NF.